# How to check user auth on each viewcontroller that requires login?

Tags: ios, swift, session, authentication

OK...so I have a swift app that connects to a PHP backend. The user logs in, it stores a session on the server and sets an encrypted cookie in the cookieStorage on the app (I also store that cookie in keychain since cookieStorage can be volatile from what I'm told). I also store the username and password in keychain as well.

The session on the server expires after a time of non-use (let's say 30 days), but if the user comes back, the session renews itself if it's under 30 days old. So for example...lets say I don't come back for 15 days...my session is now reset to 1 day old and again has 30 days to expiration...however, if I come back on day 31, I have to re-login on the web app.

There are several viewcontrollers in this app that require the user to be logged in (a couple are uiwebviews that use the cookie to access the data on the server...those aren't a problem as they handle the sessions like a champ by default). The native views (tableview, etc) that require the user be logged in however are a different story.

Currently, on login, I set a switch in NSUserDefaults that the user is logged in...in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I just check to make sure the user is logged in...if they are logged in, we move them into the "private" area of the app, if they aren't logged in, we move them to the login screen (or signup screen).

All of this is fine and good...but with the sessions expiring on the server, I was wondering what is an appropriate way of handling this in an iOS app? I want them to stay logged in until they choose otherwise, but if the app stays closed for 31 days, the session on the server will no longer be valid. I was thinking that I could set a date in UserDefaults (last time app was opened) or something like that, and if they haven't opened the app in over 30 days, then I could just use the username and password stored in keychain to re-log them into the PHP backend and refresh their session and reset the stored login date (if the password is no longer valid, I would of course redirect to login view).

Is there a more appropriate way to handle this in an iOS app or does that sound like a valid approach? Should the date/session check be in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and also in `applicationDidBecomeActive` ?

Comment: Is it a security issue if a user makes changes to the items in `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean. If you are asking that because you think that's something that is happening now...it's not. If you are asking because that's something to do with an answer you are thinking of...I'd love to hear it.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is not secure, a user can rather easily change the contents.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't store anything that has to do with the login state in the `userDefaults` it's not secure.

Second, since you are storing the username and password in the keychain, why don't you just check the keychain and log the user in every time they open the app. This will give the user a persistent login until they log out then you can clear the keychain.  Also this will give you another analytic point you can store in your database so you know every time the user opens your app.

Is there a reason you want to have a 30 day expiration?

Comment: Just keeping the DB cleared of stagnant sessions really.

Comment: Also, I figured checking a stored date would be much faster than hitting the server every time with a login request...only checking after inactivity of 30 days seems like the less intensive way of doing things all around. Would you not agree?

Comment: The hit on the DB for a login should be very minimal. This approach also allows you to shorten the server sessions to reduce the overhead of having many open, inactive sessions.

Comment: The hit on the DB isn't my concern...the request from the app to the DB and causing the user to have to wait for that split second (potentially longer depending on connection speed) for the request to return for them to be able to start moving about is my concern there. If it happens every time the app becomes active, then that could potentially be a lot of extra hits on the DB as well.

Comment: Ultimately it comes down to the level of security you need vs usability. In any case I would not us the user defaults to store anything having to do with login state.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!